# First evaluate in place all subexpressions matching pattern before substituting result

Tags: function-construction, replacement, expression-manipulation, built-in-symbols

`ReplaceAll[expr, {patt1:>rhs1, patt2:>rhs2, …}]` works by looking for and making all possible replacements of subexpressions in `expr` with `rhs1`,`rhs2`… that match `patt1`,`patt2`….  Then, the main evaluator evaluates all the `rhs1`, `rhs2`… appearing in the modified `expr`.

This scheme of replacement works well especially if `rhs1`,`rhs2`… cause side effects (like `i++`).  However, if `rhs1`,`rhs2`… are computationally intensive functions *without* side effects, and `expr` is a large expression containing many instances matching `patt1`,`patt2`…,  the main evaluator ends up evaluating the big functions `rhs1`,`rhs2`… many times.

The canonical solution to this problem in *Mathematica* is *memoization* where `rhs` is supposed to be defined like `rhs := rhs = ...` so that *even though* many instances of `rhs1`,`rhs2`… appear in the modified `expr`, the main evaluator will recognize precomputed values based on an ever growing list of `DownValues`.

**However**, I believe another possible solution to this problem, especially suitable if `rhs1`,`rhs2`… are not recursive functions, is to follow a different scheme: (1) scout out and note the positions of subexpressions in `expr` uniquely matching the `patt1`, `patt2`, (2) evaluate *in place* the corresponding `rhs1`,`rhs2`… exactly once for each unique match, and finally (3) substitute all results into `expr` at their noted positions.  I believe that apart from saving some memory, this scheme has the advantage of (a) not rebuilding a hash table of memoized `DownValues`, (b) not looking for a possible match in the hash table, and (c) not scanning the entire `expr` each time `rhs` is evaluated in the modified `expr`.

So my question is: is there a built-in replacement function that implements the replacement scheme described above?  I would find it useful.  Otherwise, is there a method to write a top-level implementation of the scheme?

Here is a first-attempt at an implementation:

```
ClearAll[ReplaceAllOnce];
ReplaceAllOnce[expr_, rules_] := 
  ReplacePart[expr, (Position[expr, #, {0, Infinity}, Heads -> True] -> (Replace[#, rules])) & /@ 
    DeleteDuplicates[Cases[expr, Alternatives @@ rules[[All, 1]], {0, Infinity}, Heads -> True]]]
```

However, I don't like it much because it has to traverse through `expr` multiple times.

---

As requested, here is an example.  Suppose I want to apply to this expression,

```
expr := (a parity[1] + b parity[2] + c parity[3])*
            (d parity[1] + e parity[2] + f parity[3]);
```

The following set of rules

```
rules = {parity[x_Integer?OddQ] :> (Pause[1]; 1), 
         parity[x_Integer?EvenQ] :> (Pause[1]; 2)};
```

A straightforward `ReplaceAll` takes 6 seconds (because there are 6 instances of `parity`).

```
ReplaceAll[expr, rules] // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {6.00317, (a + 2 b + c) (d + 2 e + f)}  *)
```

Then using the search-and-replace once method using `ReplaceAllOnce` proposed above takes only 3 seconds, and uses 5680 bytes of memory according to `MemoryInUse[]`:

```
ReplaceAllOnce[expr, rules] // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {3.00413, (a + 2 b + c) (d + 2 e + f)}  *)
```

The timing is similar to using memoization, but this uses 12800 bytes (larger, to store the memoized cases):

```
Clear[parity];
parity[x_Integer?OddQ]  := parity[x] = (Pause[1]; 1);
parity[x_Integer?EvenQ] := parity[x] = (Pause[1]; 2);

expr // AbsoluteTiming
(* {3.00486, (a + 2 b + c) (d + 2 e + f)} *)
```

Comment: Could you include an actual small example that strongly differentiates the two behaviors? A contrived one would be fine too.

Comment: @MarcoB I have added the example

Comment: I will just point out that my memoization approach only does 2 pauses, and so it is both faster and uses less memory then your approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let me discourage you from solutions using `Position` to find the places where the rules should be applied. At least, if you want to reproduce the behavior of `ReplaceAll`: `ReplaceAll` goes from the trunk to the leaves. Once a substitution is made, no more substitutions are done in the parts.

Consider for example

```
a + b f[x] /. {b y_f :> r[1], f[y_] :> r[2]}
(*a + r[1]*)
```

If the substitution started at the leaves, the result should have been `a + b r[2]`. That means that code similar to

```
Position[a + b f[x], Alternatives[f[y_], b y_f]]
(*{{2, 2}, {2}}*)
```

would have to check for nested positions and keep those closer to the trunk. That is not trivial and better left to be done by Mathematica.

Since we need to find the places for replacement and we cannot use `Position`, we should use `ReplaceAll`. Here, the [answer by Coolwater](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/179070/8803) almost hits the right spot. If one checks carefully, that answer traverses `expr` twice.

Memoization should be your best approach, but your comment on [Carl Woll's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/178409/8803) leads me to believe that you might be worried about polluting the namespace. [**Edit**: Actually, I do not understand why you have the constraint against memoization. See appended paragraphs]

The following code is not what I consider the best approach:

```
ReplaceAllOnceH[expr_, rules_List] := 
 With[{t = System`Utilities`HashTable[]}, 
  ReplaceAll[expr, 
   Replace[rules, 
    HoldPattern[
      a_ :> b_] :> (Pattern[vv$, a] :> 
       If[System`Utilities`HashTableContainsQ[t, vv$], 
        System`Utilities`HashTableGet[t, vv$], 
        With[{v = b}, System`Utilities`HashTableAdd[t, vv$, v]; 
         v]]), {1}]]]
```

It is basically a poor man's memoization. However, let us review how it stands against your claims on a method based on `Position`:

> (a) not rebuilding a hash table of memoized DownValues,
>   (b) not looking for a possible match in the hash table, and
>   (c) not scanning the entire expr each time rhs is evaluated in the modified expr.

(a) Rebuilding a hash table is [expensive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Advantages) only when going over the size of the bucket.
(b) Looking up in a hash table is an O(1) operation (on average).
(c) Done by `ReplaceAll`.

---

PS. In my computer, `ReplaceAllOnceH` is barely faster than `MemoizedReplaceAll` in some cases and barely slower in others.

---

Could you elaborate on your requirement against memoization?

If it is about memory consumption, you could use `Clear` to remove the memoized values. Or you could use something similar to the solution above where the hash table is destroyed automatically at the end of the replacement.

If it is speed, unless you have a set of expressions where you know that `Position` will not lead to nested replacements, then you would have to check for nested position. Otherwise, you could be spending resources on computing a replacement that you will not use. For example,

```
(1 + a b + (a + (1 + a b) c) d)/(b + (1 + b c) d)
Position[%, 1 + _]
(*the above yields 3 positions*)
ReplacePart[%%, Thread[% -> Extract[%%, %, Framed]]]
(*there are only two boxes in the result*)
```

Having only two boxes in the result emulates the behavior of `ReplaceAll` but there were 3 calculations done.

Now, manipulating the results of `Position` to remove the nested replacements is an operation that grows like the square of the number of replacements. Memoization grows linearly.

Answer (score 4):

In case you do have some knowledge about the expressions to be replaced and you can confidently predict that `Position` will not lead to nested replacements, you might still want to use a hash table to hold the intermediate results.

```
ReplaceAllOnceH2[expr_, rules_List] := 
 With[{p = Position[expr, Alternatives @@ rules[[All, 1]]], 
   t = System`Utilities`HashTable[]}, 
  ReplacePart[expr, 
   Thread[p -> 
     Extract[expr, p, 
      If[System`Utilities`HashTableContainsQ[t, #], 
        System`Utilities`HashTableGet[t, #], 
        With[{w = Replace[#, rules]}, 
         System`Utilities`HashTableAdd[t, #, w]; w]] &]]]]
```

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:** Carl Woll's answer made me realize it should be done differently. The code below `Sow`s the replacement values (wrapped by `eval` and `Hold`), because these may be non-injective wrt. the variables in the patterns.

`eval` prevents the second `ReplaceAll` from replacing parts that didn't match the pattern in the first place. `Hold` prevents evaluation until the association is constructed (whereby duplicates are deleted). `First` is applied to release `Hold`.

```
replaceOnce[expr_, rules_] := Module[{eval, expr2, reap},
 {expr2, {reap}} = Reap[expr /. Fold[MapAt[#2, #, {All, 2}] &, rules, {Hold, eval, Sow}]];
 expr2 /. First @@@ AssociationThread[reap -> reap]]

replaceOnce[expr, rules] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {2.0040347, (a + 2 b + c) (d + 2 e + f)}

**Old answer:**

You can use `ReplaceAll` to find the cases and `Sow` them as non-delayed rules. By putting the non-delayed rules in an `Association`, duplicates are automatically deleted. The association holds the evaluation, however, so `Map[Identity]` is applied.

Even if your `rules` is short, there may be many distinct matches, and if that is case replacing with an `Association` is usually preferable.

```
evaluateRules[expr_, rules_List] :=
     Module[{eval, rules2 = rules},
        rules2[[All, 1]] = eval /@ rules2[[All, 1]];
        Identity /@ (Association[Reap[expr /. #;][[2, 1]]] /. rules2) &[
            Pattern[a, #] :> Sow[a -> eval[a]] & /@ rules[[All, 1]]]]

expr /. evaluateRules[expr, rules] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {3.0014318, (a + 2 b + c) (d + 2 e + f)}

Comment: Interesting!  Does `Dispatch@Rules[...]` accomplish the same job as `Association` in terms of dealing with many distinct possible matches?  Does it work even if the rules have `Condition` or `PatternTest` on them?

Comment: @QuantumDot Yes but basically every time I have tried both, `Association` were faster than `Dispatch`. In this case the association is modified after its construction, so it be immediately replaced by `Dispatch`.

Comment: @QuantumDot The rules in the association are verbatim. The conditions are handled (and the result `Sow`ed) before constructing the associaition.

Answer (score 3):

### 1.05174 seconds

This is very simple, first get the [`Position`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Position.html), then evaluate only the rules that are been used (non empty `Position` list ) using [`ParallelTable`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParallelTable.html) to avoid sequential evaluation. Using `Table` would take 2 seconds.

```
expr := (a parity[1] + b parity[2] + c parity[3])*(d parity[1] + 
     e parity[2] + f parity[3]);

rules = {
   parity[x_Integer?OddQ] :> (Pause[1]; 1),
   parity[x_Integer?EvenQ] :> (Pause[1]; 2),
   nonexistent[_] :> (Pause[1]; 0)
   };

LaunchKernels[]
ClearAll[replacerh];
replacerh[expr_, rules_] := With[
  {pos = Position[expr, #] & /@ rules[[All, 1]]},
  ReplacePart[expr,
   ParallelTable[
    If[
     Length[pos[[k]]] > 0,
     pos[[k]] -> rules[[k, 2]],
     Nothing
     ]
    , {k, Length[pos]}
    ]
   ]
  ]

replacerh[expr, rules] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {1.05174, (a + 2 b + c) (d + 2 e + f)} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an implementation of the memoization approach:

```
SetAttributes[memoize,HoldAll];

memoize[a_] := memoize[a] = a

MemoizedReplaceAll[expr_, lhs_:>rhs_] := Internal`InheritedBlock[{memoize},
    ReplaceAll[expr, lhs :> memoize[rhs]]
]

MemoizedReplaceAll[expr_,rules_List] := Internal`InheritedBlock[{memoize},
    With[{new=Replace[rules, RuleDelayed[lhs_, rhs_] :> lhs:>memoize[rhs], {1}]},
        ReplaceAll[expr, new]
    ]
]
```

An example:

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = RandomInteger[10, {10, 10}]
```

> {{1, 4, 0, 7, 0, 0, 8, 6, 0, 4}, {1, 8, 5, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 10, 1}, {6, 0, 2, 6,
>      4, 5, 4, 3, 0, 1}, {3, 5, 3, 0, 3, 2, 3, 9, 5, 1}, {5, 2, 3, 9, 1, 0, 4, 4,
>      1, 5}, {2, 7, 9, 9, 8, 10, 0, 10, 10, 7}, {4, 9, 2, 6, 3, 2, 1, 1, 6, 
>     1}, {1, 6, 8, 6, 5, 6, 0, 10, 7, 9}, {1, 4, 4, 10, 3, 5, 2, 3, 1, 2}, {5, 
>     10, 8, 3, 6, 3, 10, 3, 10, 3}}

Two functions that are slow:

```
f[x_] := (Pause[.5]; x^2)
g[x_] := (Pause[.5]; x^3)
```

Using [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll) vs `MemoizedReplaceAll`:

```
r1 = ReplaceAll[data, x_?PrimeQ :> f[x]]; //AbsoluteTiming
r2 = MemoizedReplaceAll[data, x_?PrimeQ :> f[x]]; //AbsoluteTiming

r1===r2
```

> {18.0379, Null}
>
> {2.00427, Null}
>
> True

Comment: Thanks for your implementation using *memoization*.  But, I'm looking for something different (see paragraph starting with **However**): one in which the expression is first scanned to check the unique rules that can be applied, right hand sides are evaluated next, and finally the results substituted.